# Angular: How to Subscribe to Multiple Parts of Observable inside Service with Router Events

Tags: angular, observable

In my navigation service, I would like to subscribe to the current selected route url and data in one subscription.

To subscribe to the route url, I would write:

```
constructor( router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute ) {
    router.events.pipe(
        filter( event => event instanceof NavigationEnd ),
        map( () => activatedRoute ),
        map( r => {
            while ( r.firstChild ) {
                r = r.firstChild;
            }
            return r;
        } ),
        switchMap( route => route.url ),
    ).subscribe( u => {
        // ... do something with u
    } );
}
```

Now I want to also subscribe to the data-Observable of the current route. How can I split the observable to an url-part and a data-part and subscribe once for both observables?

I tried `zip()`, `partition()`, `combineLatest()` but did not succeed. Or should I use `concatMap()` ?

Comment: Take a look at the `merge` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use combine latest to unite 2 streams of url and data

```
switchMap(route => combineLatest([route.url, route.data]))
```

Comment: This would only trigger when `router.events` emits a value though, not when `router.data` changes

Comment: true, but these 2 sources are interdependant in this particular case. router.data changes just when the NavigationEnd happends. so it should work just fine here

Comment: But inside `withLatestFrom( route.data )`, `route` is not defined

Comment: oups, that should be `activatedRoute.data`. I will update the answer

Comment: @Andrei: in `withLatestFrom( activatedRoute.data )`, `activatedRoute.data` is also empty (and  yes, I double-checked the routes).

Comment: lets say you have path /a/b/c. is the activatedRoute corresponds to the '/a' portion of the path?

Comment: Yes, it's the `a`-part

Comment: then try `switchMap(route => combineLatest([route.url, route.data]))`. with your case data stream could also be difficult to find, because it can be passed from any level

Comment: Yes! That's it. Change your answer accordingly so I can accept it. Thank you very much!